# Rails uninitialized constant Bundler (NameError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundler

I'm getting the following error when running any rails commands like `rails s` or `rails c`, it's also preventing my heroku app from starting (same error):

```
app/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>': uninitialized constant Bundler (NameError)
from /Users/you/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:126:in `require'
```

Line 7 in the error message is:

```
Bundler.require(:default, Rails.env)
```

Doing the commands as `bundle exec rails s` succeeds, but that doesn't help the heroku app. I've verified `which ruby`, `which rails` and `which bundler`. I've also tried starting a new rvm gemset and reinstalling the bundle. The heroku error is identical:

```
 /app/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>': uninitialized constant Bundler (NameError)
```

running `bundle check` returns no issues.

Some similar questions suggested this:

```
 bundle config --delete bin    # Turn off Bundler's stub generator
 rake rails:update:bin         # Use the new Rails 4 executables
 git add bin                   # Add bin/ to source control
```

But I tried it and got no changes. I'm on Rails 4

edit:

I was working in another app and ran `rails g model` and this popped up:

```
Bundler is using a binstub that was created for a different gem.
This is deprecated, in future versions you may need to `bundle binstub rails` to work around a system/bundle conflict.
```

gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '2.0.0'
gem 'rails', '4.0.3'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.1'
gem 'uglifier'
gem 'coffee-rails'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder'
gem 'bcrypt-ruby'
gem "geocoder"
gem 'gmaps4rails'
gem "paperclip"
gem 'route_translator'
gem 'aws-sdk'
gem 'ckeditor'
gem 'soundcloud'
gem 'omniauth-facebook'
gem 'twitter'
gem 'pg'
gem 'unicorn'
gem 'sass'
gem 'compass', '0.12.2'
gem 'font-awesome-rails'
gem 'acts-as-taggable-on'
gem 'json', '1.7.7'
gem 'figaro'

#for mailchimp api
gem 'gibbon'

#for deploying
gem 'capistrano', '~> 3.0.1'
gem 'capistrano-rails', '~> 1.1.0'
gem 'capistrano-bundler'
gem 'capistrano-rbenv', '~> 2.0'
gem 'exception_notification'
gem 'textacular'
gem 'mail_form'
gem 'dumper'

group :doc do
  gem 'sdoc', require: false
end

# development gems
group :development, :test do
       # env variables
  gem "faker"
end

# Paging
gem 'kaminari'
gem 'will_paginate-bootstrap', '~> 1.0.0'

# Slugs and friendly id's
gem 'friendly_id'

# font-awesome
gem 'font-awesome-sass', '~> 4.0.2'

# production gems for heroku
group :production do
  gem 'rails_12factor'
  gem 'therubyracer'
  gem 'execjs'
end


# Devise
gem 'devise'


gem 'chosen-rails'


# Bootstrap 3
group :development, :test do
  gem 'rails_layout'  # Bootstrap 3 layout generator
end

gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.0.3.0'   


# RSpec
group :test, :development do
  gem "rspec-rails"
  gem "factory_girl_rails"
end

# Capybara
group :test do
  gem "capybara"
  gem 'email_spec'
end
```

gemfile.lock

GEM

```
  remote: https://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    actionmailer (4.0.3)
      actionpack (= 4.0.3)
      mail (~> 2.5.4)
    actionpack (4.0.3)
      activesupport (= 4.0.3)
      builder (~> 3.1.0)
      erubis (~> 2.7.0)
      rack (~> 1.5.2)
      rack-test (~> 0.6.2)
    activemodel (4.0.3)
      activesupport (= 4.0.3)
      builder (~> 3.1.0)
    activerecord (4.0.3)
      activemodel (= 4.0.3)
      activerecord-deprecated_finders (~> 1.0.2)
      activesupport (= 4.0.3)
      arel (~> 4.0.0)
    activerecord-deprecated_finders (1.0.3)
    activesupport (4.0.3)
      i18n (~> 0.6, >= 0.6.4)
      minitest (~> 4.2)
      multi_json (~> 1.3)
      thread_safe (~> 0.1)
      tzinfo (~> 0.3.37)
    acts-as-taggable-on (3.1.1)
      actionpack (>= 3, < 5)
      activerecord (>= 3, < 5)
      activesupport (>= 3, < 5)
    addressable (2.3.6)
    arel (4.0.2)
    aws-sdk (1.38.0)
      json (~> 1.4)
      nokogiri (>= 1.4.4)
      uuidtools (~> 2.1)
    bcrypt (3.1.7)
    bcrypt-ruby (3.1.5)
      bcrypt (>= 3.1.3)
    bootstrap-sass (3.0.3.0)
      sass (~> 3.2)
    builder (3.1.4)
    capistrano (3.0.1)
      i18n
      rake (>= 10.0.0)
      sshkit (>= 0.0.23)
    capistrano-bundler (1.1.2)
      capistrano (~> 3.0)
      sshkit (~> 1.2)
    capistrano-rails (1.1.0)
      capistrano (>= 3.0.0)
      capistrano-bundler (>= 1.0.0)
    capistrano-rbenv (2.0.1)
      capistrano (~> 3.0)
      sshkit (~> 1.3)
    capybara (2.2.1)
      mime-types (>= 1.16)
      nokogiri (>= 1.3.3)
      rack (>= 1.0.0)
      rack-test (>= 0.5.4)
      xpath (~> 2.0)
    chosen-rails (1.1.0)
      coffee-rails (>= 3.2)
      compass-rails (>= 1.1.2)
      railties (>= 3.0)
      sass-rails (>= 3.2)
    chunky_png (1.3.0)
    ckeditor (4.0.11)
      mime-types
      orm_adapter (~> 0.5.0)
    climate_control (0.0.3)
      activesupport (>= 3.0)
    cocaine (0.5.4)
      climate_control (>= 0.0.3, < 1.0)
    coffee-rails (4.0.1)
      coffee-script (>= 2.2.0)
      railties (>= 4.0.0, < 5.0)
    coffee-script (2.2.0)
      coffee-script-source
      execjs
    coffee-script-source (1.7.0)
    compass (0.12.2)
      chunky_png (~> 1.2)
      fssm (>= 0.2.7)
      sass (~> 3.1)
    compass-rails (1.1.7)
      compass (>= 0.12.2)
      sprockets (<= 2.11.0)
    devise (3.2.4)
      bcrypt (~> 3.0)
      orm_adapter (~> 0.1)
      railties (>= 3.2.6, < 5)
      thread_safe (~> 0.1)
      warden (~> 1.2.3)
    diff-lcs (1.2.5)
    dumper (1.5.0)
      multi_json (>= 1.0)
      multipart-post (>= 1.1.5)
      posix-spawn (>= 0.3.6)
    email_spec (1.5.0)
      launchy (~> 2.1)
      mail (~> 2.2)
    erubis (2.7.0)
    exception_notification (4.0.1)
      actionmailer (>= 3.0.4)
      activesupport (>= 3.0.4)
    execjs (2.0.2)
    factory_girl (4.4.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0.0)
    factory_girl_rails (4.4.1)
      factory_girl (~> 4.4.0)
      railties (>= 3.0.0)
    faker (1.3.0)
      i18n (~> 0.5)
    faraday (0.9.0)
      multipart-post (>= 1.2, < 3)
    figaro (0.7.0)
      bundler (~> 1.0)
      rails (>= 3, < 5)
    font-awesome-rails (4.0.3.1)
      railties (>= 3.2, < 5.0)
    font-awesome-sass (4.0.3.1)
      sass (~> 3.2)
    friendly_id (5.0.3)
      activerecord (>= 4.0.0)
    fssm (0.2.10)
    geocoder (1.2.0)
    gibbon (1.1.2)
      httparty
      multi_json (>= 1.3.4)
    gmaps4rails (2.1.2)
    hashie (2.1.1)
    hike (1.2.3)
    httmultiparty (0.3.14)
      httparty (>= 0.7.3)
      mimemagic
      multipart-post
    httparty (0.11.0)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
      multi_xml (>= 0.5.2)
    i18n (0.6.9)
    jbuilder (2.0.6)
      activesupport (>= 3.0.0, < 5)
      multi_json (~> 1.2)
    jquery-rails (3.1.0)
      railties (>= 3.0, < 5.0)
      thor (>= 0.14, < 2.0)
    json (1.7.7)
    jwt (0.1.11)
      multi_json (>= 1.5)
    kaminari (0.15.1)
      actionpack (>= 3.0.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0.0)
    kgio (2.9.2)
    launchy (2.4.2)
      addressable (~> 2.3)
    libv8 (3.16.14.3)
    mail (2.5.4)
      mime-types (~> 1.16)
      treetop (~> 1.4.8)
    mail_form (1.5.0)
      actionmailer (>= 3.2, < 5)
      activemodel (>= 3.2, < 5)
    mime-types (1.25.1)
    mimemagic (0.2.1)
    mini_portile (0.5.3)
    minitest (4.7.5)
    multi_json (1.9.2)
    multi_xml (0.5.5)
    multipart-post (2.0.0)
    net-scp (1.2.0)
      net-ssh (>= 2.6.5)
    net-ssh (2.8.0)
    nokogiri (1.6.1)
      mini_portile (~> 0.5.0)
    oauth2 (0.9.3)
      faraday (>= 0.8, < 0.10)
      jwt (~> 0.1.8)
      multi_json (~> 1.3)
      multi_xml (~> 0.5)
      rack (~> 1.2)
    omniauth (1.2.1)
      hashie (>= 1.2, < 3)
      rack (~> 1.0)
    omniauth-facebook (1.6.0)
      omniauth-oauth2 (~> 1.1)
    omniauth-oauth2 (1.1.2)
      faraday (>= 0.8, < 0.10)
      multi_json (~> 1.3)
      oauth2 (~> 0.9.3)
      omniauth (~> 1.2)
    orm_adapter (0.5.0)
    paperclip (4.1.1)
      activemodel (>= 3.0.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0.0)
      cocaine (~> 0.5.3)
      mime-types
    pg (0.17.1)
    polyglot (0.3.4)
    posix-spawn (0.3.8)
    rack (1.5.2)
    rack-test (0.6.2)
      rack (>= 1.0)
    rails (4.0.3)
      actionmailer (= 4.0.3)
      actionpack (= 4.0.3)
      activerecord (= 4.0.3)
      activesupport (= 4.0.3)
      bundler (>= 1.3.0, < 2.0)
      railties (= 4.0.3)
      sprockets-rails (~> 2.0.0)
    rails_12factor (0.0.2)
      rails_serve_static_assets
      rails_stdout_logging
    rails_layout (1.0.14)
    rails_serve_static_assets (0.0.2)
    rails_stdout_logging (0.0.3)
    railties (4.0.3)
      actionpack (= 4.0.3)
      activesupport (= 4.0.3)
      rake (>= 0.8.7)
      thor (>= 0.18.1, < 2.0)
    raindrops (0.13.0)
    rake (10.3.0)
    rdoc (3.12.2)
      json (~> 1.4)
    ref (1.0.5)
    route_translator (3.2.0)
    rspec-core (2.14.8)
    rspec-expectations (2.14.5)
      diff-lcs (>= 1.1.3, < 2.0)
    rspec-mocks (2.14.6)
    rspec-rails (2.14.2)
      actionpack (>= 3.0)
      activemodel (>= 3.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0)
      railties (>= 3.0)
      rspec-core (~> 2.14.0)
      rspec-expectations (~> 2.14.0)
      rspec-mocks (~> 2.14.0)
    sass (3.2.19)
    sass-rails (4.0.3)
      railties (>= 4.0.0, < 5.0)
      sass (~> 3.2.0)
      sprockets (~> 2.8, <= 2.11.0)
      sprockets-rails (~> 2.0)
    sdoc (0.3.20)
      json (>= 1.1.3)
      rdoc (~> 3.10)
    simple_oauth (0.2.0)
    soundcloud (0.3.2)
      hashie (~> 2.0)
      httmultiparty (~> 0.3.0)
    sprockets (2.11.0)
      hike (~> 1.2)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
      rack (~> 1.0)
      tilt (~> 1.1, != 1.3.0)
    sprockets-rails (2.0.1)
      actionpack (>= 3.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0)
      sprockets (~> 2.8)
    sshkit (1.4.0)
      net-scp (>= 1.1.2)
      net-ssh (>= 2.8.0)
      term-ansicolor
    term-ansicolor (1.3.0)
      tins (~> 1.0)
    textacular (3.2.0)
      activerecord (>= 3.0, < 4.2)
    therubyracer (0.12.1)
      libv8 (~> 3.16.14.0)
      ref
    thor (0.19.1)
    thread_safe (0.3.3)
    tilt (1.4.1)
    tins (1.1.0)
    treetop (1.4.15)
      polyglot
      polyglot (>= 0.3.1)
    turbolinks (2.2.2)
      coffee-rails
    twitter (4.8.1)
      faraday (~> 0.8, < 0.10)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
      simple_oauth (~> 0.2)
    tzinfo (0.3.39)
    uglifier (2.2.1)
      execjs (>= 0.3.0)
      multi_json (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.2)
    unicorn (4.8.2)
      kgio (~> 2.6)
      rack
      raindrops (~> 0.7)
    uuidtools (2.1.4)
    warden (1.2.3)
      rack (>= 1.0)
    will_paginate (3.0.5)
    will_paginate-bootstrap (1.0.0)
      will_paginate (>= 3.0.3)
    xpath (2.0.0)
      nokogiri (~> 1.3)

PLATFORMS
  ruby

DEPENDENCIES
  acts-as-taggable-on
  aws-sdk
  bcrypt-ruby
  bootstrap-sass (~> 3.0.3.0)
  capistrano (~> 3.0.1)
  capistrano-bundler
  capistrano-rails (~> 1.1.0)
  capistrano-rbenv (~> 2.0)
  capybara
  chosen-rails
  ckeditor
  coffee-rails
  compass (= 0.12.2)
  devise
  dumper
  email_spec
  exception_notification
  execjs
  factory_girl_rails
  faker
  figaro
  font-awesome-rails
  font-awesome-sass (~> 4.0.2)
  friendly_id
  geocoder
  gibbon
  gmaps4rails
  jbuilder
  jquery-rails
  json (= 1.7.7)
  kaminari
  mail_form
  omniauth-facebook
  paperclip
  pg
  rails (= 4.0.3)
  rails_12factor
  rails_layout
  route_translator
  rspec-rails
  sass
  sass-rails (~> 4.0.1)
  sdoc
  soundcloud
  textacular
  therubyracer
  turbolinks
  twitter
  uglifier
  unicorn
  will_paginate-bootstrap (~> 1.0.0)
```

update2: If I clone the repo and `bundle install`, and the try to run `rails s` or any rake task, I replicate the `bundler` errors. However, if I then do `gem install bundler` and `gem install rake`, the new repo will work fine. Uninstalling and reinstalling the two gems in my original repo will not fix the issue. glad I've found a quasi fix, but would still like to get to the bottom of this.

update3: I think I've narrowed it down to an issue with the gems, but not sure how to proceed. If I run the commands that trigger errors using my default gemset, there is no issue, it's only when I switch over to the gemset for this project that I get errors. I did not run `bundle update` before testing commands with the default gemset.

update4: I've cloned the repo on another machine and it replicates the issue. So I'm guessing it's time to start going back and checking commits from before this issue and see what happens? My other idea is to start commenting out gems / removing dependencies and seeing if that helps. Anything else I might want to look at?

After removing all gems, the warning with `uninitialized constant` is still present.

Comment: Can you share your Gemfile and Gemfile.lock?

Comment: I added them. Also tried cloning the repo on another computer and it throws the same errors, which leads to be believe it's not a system issue but something with my files. Not quite sure where to look anymore since all the related questions are just un/installing bundler

Answer (score 19, accepted):

These commands from the [bundler FAQ](https://github.com/bundler/bundler/blob/master/ISSUES.md) did the trick:

```
#remove project-specific settings
rm -rf .bundle/

# remove project-specific cached gems and repos
rm -rf vendor/cache/

# remove the saved resolve of the Gemfile
rm -rf Gemfile.lock
```

and then rebundling with `bundle install`

edit: heroku deploy was also failing to start up because it starts the server with bin/rails s and my binstubs were all wonky. to fix this: `BUNDLE INSTALL --BINSTUBS`, again from [bundler docs](http://bundler.io/v1.6/man/bundle-exec.1.html)

Comment: Oh my. One should not `rm Gemfile.lock` and `bundle install` without understanding that its basically means upgrading ALL gems.

Comment: you can specify explicit versions and prevent major version changes in your gemfile before you delete it if that's concern

Comment: I just ran the first two commands without removing Gemfile.lock and it worked like a charm. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I just removed the lock using `rm -rf Gemfile.lock` within my project directory's root folder, and re-ran  `bundle install` and everything works perfect now.

Answer (score 0):

I have problems like you, subscribe my case.

**config/applicataion.rb:**

```
require_relative 'boot'

require 'rails/all'

# Require the gems listed in Gemfile, including any gems
# you've limited to :test, :development, or :production.
Bundler.require(*Rails.groups)

module AppName
  class Application < Rails::Application
    config.load_defaults 5.2
  end
end
```

where `require_relative 'boot'` is very important, such as **config/boot.rb**:

```
ENV['BUNDLE_GEMFILE'] ||= File.expand_path('../Gemfile', __dir__)

require 'bundler/setup' # Set up gems listed in the Gemfile.
```

has including bundler library into application.