# NameError: uninitialized constant Bundler

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, bundler

I just changed my webserver to Puma and had to change my development DB from sqlite to postgresql. but now I'm getting this error everytime I try to run 'rake db:migrate':

```
rake aborted!
NameError: uninitialized constant Bundler
C:/Sites/dawnrebirth/config/application.rb:7:in <top (required)>'
C:/Sites/dawnrebirth/Rakefile:4:in <top (required)>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

my gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
gem 'rails', '4.2.1'
gem 'pg'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc
group :development, :test do
  gem 'byebug'
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'
  gem 'better_errors', '~> 2.1.1'
  gem 'annotate', '~> 2.6.10'
  gem 'binding_of_caller'
 end
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]

gem 'devise', '~> 3.5.1'
gem 'haml', '~> 4.0.6'
gem 'sass', '~> 3.4.14'
gem 'paperclip', '~> 4.3.0'
gem 'babosa', '~> 1.0.2'
gem 'rails-i18n', '~> 4.0.4'
gem 'devise-i18n', '~> 0.12.1'
gem 'simple_form', '~> 3.1.0'
gem 'dotiw'
gem 'paperclip-dropbox', '~> 1.3.2'
gem 'rmagick', '~> 2.15.3', group: :production
gem 'masonry-rails', '~> 0.2.4'
gem 'rufus-scheduler', '~> 3.1.3'
gem 'jquery-turbolinks'
gem 'puma'
gem 'rails_12factor', group: :production
gem 'mailboxer'
gem 'acts_as_votable'

ruby "2.1.5"
```

EDIT:

running `bundle exec rake db:migrate` works and successfully migrates my db.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23130295/rails-uninitialized-constant-bundler-nameerror

Answer (score 1):

Install the `bundler` gem:

```
gem install bundler
```

Then, try again.

#### Update

If the above does not work, try:

```
rm -rf .bundle/
rm -rf vendor/cache/
```

Then try again.

If this does not work, you may try removing `Gemfile.lock` which is not recommended (but if you are just starting your project and no one else is having `Gemfile.lock` in their machine, you can do this):

```
rm -rf Gemfile.lock
```

Comment: Try this: `rm -rf .bundle/` and then `bundle install`

Comment: do you have your project on github?

Comment: No  I don't have it on github

Comment: Its hard to tell what going on without being able to try it locally.