# Trouble starting my rails server all of a sudden

Tags: ruby-on-rails, command, command-prompt

```
C:\Users\Josh\Sites\simple_cms>rails server
C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/va
lues/time_zone.rb:282: warning: circular argument reference - now
C:/Users/Josh/Sites/simple_cms/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>': un
initialized constant Bundler (NameError)
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_req
uire.rb:54:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_req
uire.rb:54:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/com
mands.rb:76:in `block in <top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/com
mands.rb:73:in `tap'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/com
mands.rb:73:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_req
uire.rb:128:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_req
uire.rb:128:in `rescue in require'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_req
uire.rb:39:in `require'
        from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'

C:\Users\Josh\Sites\simple_cms>
```

This is the file in config/application.rb

```
require File.expand_path('../boot', __FILE__)

require 'rails/all'
```

# Require the gems listed in Gemfile, including any gems
   # you've limited to :test, :development, or :production.
   Bundler.require(:default, Rails.env)

```
module SimpleCms
  class Application < Rails::Application
    # Settings in config/environments/* take precedence over those specified    here.
    # Application configuration should go into files in config/initializers
    # -- all .rb files in that directory are automatically loaded.

    # Set Time.zone default to the specified zone and make Active Record auto-convert to this zone.
    # Run "rake -D time" for a list of tasks for finding time zone names. Default is UTC.
       # config.time_zone = 'Central Time (US & Canada)'

        # The default locale is :en and all translations from     config/locales/*.rb,yml are auto loaded.
    # config.i18n.load_path += Dir[Rails.root.join('my', 'locales', '*.           {rb,yml}').to_s]
    # config.i18n.default_locale = :de
  end
end
```

Comment: It seems you did something wrong about your references. Copy your models references here.

Comment: where do i get this?? im sorry im new :( @AliSepehri.Kh

Comment: I'm not sure. Apparently your main problem is config/application.rb file.

Comment: check out this question(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23130295/rails-uninitialized-constant-bundler-nameerror)